# Deconfigure an interface in IOS with one command

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

I was wondering if there is a single command to clear a single network port's configuration? (wipe switchport, portsecurity,...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In global configuration mode, typing `default interface [the interface]` will clear the interface's configuration in the running-config.

Comment: Whenever you repurpose an interace, the safest action is to reset it to default. That way you can be sure to only have the settings you want.

Comment: Beware, if you have commands on an interface that effect a port group (such as vlan maps on a 6500) the default command will remove those from the entire port group.

Comment: Yep, this is the easiest way. Additionally you might want to shutdown the port, 'default interface' doesn't do that for you.

Comment: @TeunVink, actually that depends if the interface is shutdown by default or not and this will vary depending on platform/version of IOS.